# How to POST text/uri-list using RestKit

Tags: ios, rest, restkit, spring-data-rest

it's my first post on StackOverflow :)

We're writing RESTful API backend using Spring Data Rest. To add association we're using the request:

```
POST /favouriteFolders/7/posts HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Type: text/uri-list

http://localhost:8080/posts/68
http://localhost:8080/posts/418
```

Request format is described here:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.5.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#_post_2

Our iOS developer has problem sending this kind of request using RestKit
https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit

Any ideas how to use RestKit in this situation?
Or maybe we should use other REST client to handle this specific requests ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome. You need to give more details of what you tried, how close you got, what went wrong. What options you've considered at least.

Comment: I've had to wait for my developer to describe situation in details and now... he solved it ;) Sorry for trouble you, and thanks for your response.

Comment: Please delete the question or add more detail and an answer